# How to weld objects and add fin-like object THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a scene that revolves around a rocket ship that orbits certain planets etc.

I am firstly starting off by creating my own rocketship object. I am trying to recreate a model that look similar to this `https://kyleagnew.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/lowpolyrocket5.jpg`

And this is the current model that I have created `https://jsfiddle.net/pfya1sjm/4/`

As you can tell by my model, it consists of a lot of objects created and aligned with each other using the y axis. This also means that the object doesn't look completely smooth as you can see all the lines between them. Is there a way I can avoid this or weld all the objects together so they become one smooth object?

Also, for the second part of the question, how could I create fin-like objects that stick out the bottom of the rocket? as displayed on the example im trying to remake.

<-----------------------EDIT-------------------------->

```
// once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
            $(function() {

                var stats = initStats();

                // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();

                // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

                // create a render and set the size
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

                renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

                window.addEventListener('resize', function()
            {
                var width = window.innerWidth;
                var height = window.innerHeight;
                renderer.setSize(width, height);
                camera.aspect = width / height;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            } );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            // create the object group that contains all the sub-shapes
            var rocketGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
            scene.add(rocketGroup);

            var rocketMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xEEEEEE});
            var hingeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFD1414});
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var rocketAntennaOne = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 2, 2, 11 );   
            var rocketAntennaOneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketAntennaOne, hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());            
            var rocketAntennaTwo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 2, 3, 1, 11 );            
            var rocketAntennaTwoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketAntennaTwo, hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketAntennaThree = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 3, 4, 1, 11 );
            var rocketAntennaThreeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( rocketAntennaThree,hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var rocketBodyOne = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 4, 8, 6, 11 );   
            var rocketBodyOneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyOne,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodyTwo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 8, 11, 6, 11 );   
            var rocketBodyTwoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyTwo,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodyThree = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 11, 14, 6, 11 );   
            var rocketBodyThreeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyThree,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodyFour = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 14, 15, 6, 11 );   
            var rocketBodyFourMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyFour,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodyFive = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 15, 16, 6, 11 );   
            var rocketBodyFiveMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyFive,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodySix = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 16, 16, 7, 11 );   
            var rocketBodySixMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodySix,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodySeven = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 16, 15, 6, 11 );   
            var rocketBodySevenMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodySeven,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodyEight = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 15, 14, 6, 11 ); 
            var rocketBodyEightMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyEight,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodyNine = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 14, 13, 6, 11 ); 
            var rocketBodyNineMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyNine,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            var rocketBodyTen = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 13, 12, 6, 11 ); 
            var rocketBodyTenMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyTen,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
            var rocketBodyUpper = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 7, 8, 7, 10 );
            var rocketBodyUpperMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyUpper,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());            
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
            var rocketBodyLower = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5.5, 6, 5, 10 );
            var rocketBodyLowerMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyLower,rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());



            //////////////////////////////////////
            scene.add(rocketAntennaOneMesh);
            scene.add(rocketAntennaTwoMesh);
            scene.add(rocketAntennaThreeMesh);
            /////////////////////////////////////
            scene.add(rocketBodyOneMesh);
            scene.add(rocketBodyTwoMesh);  
            scene.add(rocketBodyThreeMesh);  
            scene.add(rocketBodyFourMesh);  
            scene.add(rocketBodyFiveMesh);  
            scene.add(rocketBodySixMesh);
            scene.add(rocketBodySevenMesh);  
            scene.add(rocketBodyEightMesh);
            scene.add(rocketBodyNineMesh);  
            scene.add(rocketBodyTenMesh);
            ///////////////////////////////////////
            scene.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);
            scene.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);

            //Specify the position of the rocket cone
            rocketAntennaOneMesh.position.y = 74;
            rocketAntennaTwoMesh.position.y = 72.5;
            rocketAntennaThreeMesh.position.y = 71.5;
            rocketBodyOneMesh.position.y = 68;
            rocketBodyTwoMesh.position.y = 62;
            rocketBodyThreeMesh.position.y = 56;
            rocketBodyFourMesh.position.y = 50;
            rocketBodyFiveMesh.position.y = 44;
            rocketBodySixMesh.position.y = 37.5;
            rocketBodySevenMesh.position.y = 31;
            rocketBodyEightMesh.position.y = 25;
            rocketBodyNineMesh.position.y = 19;
            rocketBodyTenMesh.position.y = 13;


            rocketBodyUpperMesh.position.y = 10;
            rocketBodyLowerMesh.position.y = 7;


            //Add the rocketCone to the lowpolyRocket group
            rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaOneMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaTwoMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaTwoMesh);
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyOneMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyTwoMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyThreeMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyFourMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyFiveMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodySixMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodySevenMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyEightMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyNineMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyTenMesh);
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);
            rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyLowerMesh);


                // create the ground plane
                var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60, 20);
                var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
                var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
                plane.receiveShadow = true;

                // rotate and position the plane
                plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
                plane.position.x = 15;

                // add the plane to the scene
                scene.add(plane);

                // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
                camera.position.x = -150;
                camera.position.y = 110;
                camera.position.z = 20;
                camera.lookAt(scene.position);

                // add subtle ambient lighting
                var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
                scene.add(ambientLight);

                // add spotlight for the shadows
                var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
                spotLight.position.set(-70, 60, -10);
                spotLight.castShadow = true;
                scene.add(spotLight);

                // add the output of the renderer to the html element
                $("#WebGL-output").append(renderer.domElement);

                var controls = new function() {

                };


                // call the render function
                var angle = 0;
                render();

                function render() {

                }

                function initStats() {

                    var stats = new Stats();

                    stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

                    // Align top-left
                    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                    stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
                    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

                    $("#Stats-output").append(stats.domElement);

                    return stats;
                }
            });
```

JSFiddle code:

```js
// create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

// create a render and set the size
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

});

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// create the object group that contains all the sub-shapes
var rocketGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(rocketGroup);

var rocketMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xEEEEEE
});
var hingeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xFD1414
});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var rocketAntennaOne = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 2, 2, 11);
var rocketAntennaOneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketAntennaOne, hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketAntennaTwo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 3, 1, 11);
var rocketAntennaTwoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketAntennaTwo, hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketAntennaThree = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(3, 4, 1, 11);
var rocketAntennaThreeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketAntennaThree, hingeMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var rocketBodyOne = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(4, 8, 6, 11);
var rocketBodyOneMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyOne, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodyTwo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(8, 11, 6, 11);
var rocketBodyTwoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyTwo, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodyThree = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(11, 14, 6, 11);
var rocketBodyThreeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyThree, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodyFour = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(14, 15, 6, 11);
var rocketBodyFourMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyFour, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodyFive = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(15, 16, 6, 11);
var rocketBodyFiveMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyFive, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodySix = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(16, 16, 7, 11);
var rocketBodySixMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodySix, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodySeven = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(16, 15, 6, 11);
var rocketBodySevenMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodySeven, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodyEight = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(15, 14, 6, 11);
var rocketBodyEightMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyEight, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodyNine = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(14, 13, 6, 11);
var rocketBodyNineMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyNine, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
var rocketBodyTen = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(13, 12, 6, 11);
var rocketBodyTenMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyTen, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
var rocketBodyUpper = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(7, 8, 7, 10);
var rocketBodyUpperMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyUpper, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
var rocketBodyLower = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5.5, 6, 5, 10);
var rocketBodyLowerMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketBodyLower, rocketMaterial, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial());



//////////////////////////////////////
scene.add(rocketAntennaOneMesh);
scene.add(rocketAntennaTwoMesh);
scene.add(rocketAntennaThreeMesh);
/////////////////////////////////////
scene.add(rocketBodyOneMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodyTwoMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodyThreeMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodyFourMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodyFiveMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodySixMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodySevenMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodyEightMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodyNineMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodyTenMesh);
///////////////////////////////////////
scene.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);
scene.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);

//Specify the position of the rocket cone
rocketAntennaOneMesh.position.y = 74;
rocketAntennaTwoMesh.position.y = 72.5;
rocketAntennaThreeMesh.position.y = 71.5;
rocketBodyOneMesh.position.y = 68;
rocketBodyTwoMesh.position.y = 62;
rocketBodyThreeMesh.position.y = 56;
rocketBodyFourMesh.position.y = 50;
rocketBodyFiveMesh.position.y = 44;
rocketBodySixMesh.position.y = 37.5;
rocketBodySevenMesh.position.y = 31;
rocketBodyEightMesh.position.y = 25;
rocketBodyNineMesh.position.y = 19;
rocketBodyTenMesh.position.y = 13;


rocketBodyUpperMesh.position.y = 10;
rocketBodyLowerMesh.position.y = 7;


//Add the rocketCone to the lowpolyRocket group
rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaOneMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaTwoMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketAntennaTwoMesh);
/////////////////////////////////////////
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyOneMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyTwoMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyThreeMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyFourMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyFiveMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodySixMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodySevenMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyEightMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyNineMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyTenMesh);
//////////////////////////////////////////
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyUpperMesh);
rocketGroup.add(rocketBodyLowerMesh);


var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 0.4);
scene.add(ambientLight);

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
camera.add(pointLight);
scene.add(camera);



// position and point the camera to the center of the scene
camera.position.x = -140;
camera.position.y = 20;
camera.position.z = 30;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

// game logic    
var update = function() {
  //cone.rotation.x += 0.01;
  //cone.rotation.y += 0.005;
};
// draw scene    
var render = function() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};



// run game loop (update, render, repeat)
var GameLoop = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);
  update();
  render();
};
GameLoop();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please consider including your code as a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so it can run in place without relying on an external service.

Comment: @TheJim01 I would usually add the code directly there, but I was previously recommended to use jsfiddle when displaying these 3D objects. I thought it'd help you guys understand me better

Comment: I've edited your post to include your code from JSFiddle as a snippet. Please take a look, and see that you can run it here. :) This is the preferred way of sharing because when (not if) the JSFiddle link goes bad, the context of your question will persist here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edges between your body sections appear hard because the normals for the matching vertices are different, and blend that way.

`THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` uses vertex normals for edge blending. If two normals at an edge are the same, then the edges will appear to blend together. If the normals point in different directions, the edge will appear hard.

You have a few options:

1. Edit the geometry, so that edges that meet share the same normal vector value for each of their paired vertices.
2. Manually merge the geometries into a single geometry object, then figure out the disparate normals, and configure them to use the same one.
3. Build a custom geometry definition using [`THREE.Geometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry) or [`THREE.BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry).

I'd really recommend trying out option 3, because it's likely you'll need to use that to define your "fins". You could get tricky and figure out how to position/scale/skew a primite mesh to satisfy your requirement, but building a custom geometry will (in my opinion) be MUCH easier.

Comment: how would I go about using option 3?

Comment: @zadders Stack Overflow isn't the place for extended conversations, tutorials, etc. Please take a look at the three.js [docs](https://threejs.org/docs) and [examples](https://threejs.org/examples) which provide much of the information you'll need to attempt the task. And above all, experiment and try stuff--you can't break this stuff, so there's no excuse to not be bold. And if you get stuck, come back to Stack Overflow and ask questions. :)